# Can Service Fabric Cluster Maintains the old versions of a service?

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a Micro Service in service fabric cluster which is a V1 for example. Now I upgraded it to the new version lets say v2. After a successful upgrade, Service Fabric replaced the old version with the new version of micro service. But I want to have and communicate with both versions of services. Can I achieve this in Service Fabric? If yes can anyone help me out on this?

-Kishore.

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: @kishmatuches what did you end up going with?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have multiple versions of your application running at the same time as long as they have unique application names.  See [Keep application old version running side-by-side with the newer version in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104616/keep-application-old-version-running-side-by-side-with-the-newer-version-in-azur).